# Como incrementar uma variável sob determinada condição

Tags: sql-server

Estou com um probleminha para resolver em SQL.
Necessito incrementar uma variável sel2 a partir de uma condição definida em sel1, por exemplo:

```
linha | sel1 | sel2
1     |  1   |  1
2     | -1   |  -1
3     | -1   |  -2
4     |  1   |  1
5     |  1   |  2
6     |  1   |  3
7     | -1   |  -1
```

assim por diante

tentei resolver por meio do seguinte código:

```
SELECT t1.linha ,
       t1.sel1 ,
       SUM(t2.sel1) sel2
FROM #A AS t1
INNER JOIN #A AS t2 ON t1.linha>= t2.linha
GROUP BY t1.linha,
         t1.sel1
ORDER BY t1.linha ASC
```

No entanto, o resultado incrementa acumulativamente, assim:

```
linha | sel1 | sel2
1     |  1   |  1
2     | -1   |  -1
3     | -1   |  -2
4     |  1   |  2
5     |  1   |  3
6     |  1   |  4
7     | -1   |  -3
```

O fato é que não consegui obter o resultado esperado. Será que alguém  teria alguma ideia par a solução.

agradeço

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, isto pode ser feito desta forma:

```
create table #tmp1 (Linha int, Sel1 int, Sel2 int)
go

insert into #tmp1
            select Linha = 1, Sel1 = 1, Sel2 = 0
    Union   select Linha = 2, Sel1 = -1, Sel2 = 0
    Union   select Linha = 3, Sel1 = -1, Sel2 = 0
    Union   select Linha = 4, Sel1 = 1, Sel2 = 0
    Union   select Linha = 5, Sel1 = 1, Sel2 = 0
    Union   select Linha = 6, Sel1 = 1, Sel2 = 0
    Union   select Linha = 7, Sel1 = -1, Sel2 = 0
go

select * from #tmp1

declare @sel2 int = 0
update  #tmp1
    set Sel2    =   @sel2
    ,   @sel2   =   @sel2 + Sel1

select * from #tmp1
```

Answer (score 0):

Agradeço a resposta
É interessante, no entanto o problema persiste
o caso é que a variável "sel1" é previamente definida (é ela que define a condição), se o valor seguinte é igual ao anterior, soma com o anterior, se for diferente, teria que tomar aquele valor como o início da contagem, por exemplo:

linha | sel1 | sel2
1     |  1   |  1
2     | -1   |  -1
3     | -1   |  -2
4     |  1   |  1
5     |  1   |  2
6     |  1   |  3
7     | -1   |  -1
.     |  .   |  .
.     |  .   |  .
.     |  .   |  .
Não sendo fixado o valor para "linha"
executei o código que sugeriu, mas não deu certo